# How can i show post views using specified post ID?

Tags: post-meta, views

Here is the code...

```
if ( !function_exists( 'getCrunchifyPostViews' ) ) {
function getCrunchifyPostViews($postID){
    $count_key = 'post_views_count';
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
    if($count==''){
        delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
        add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
        return "0 View";
    }
    return $count.' Views';
}
}

if ( !function_exists( 'setCrunchifyPostViews' ) ) {
function setCrunchifyPostViews($postID) {
    $count_key = 'post_views_count';
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
    if($count==''){
        $count = 0;
        delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
        add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
    }else{
        $count++;
        update_post_meta($postID, $count_key, $count);
    }
}
}

if ( !function_exists( 'mvp_post_views' ) ) {
function mvp_post_views(){
    $post_id = get_the_ID();
    $count_key = 'post_views_count';
    $n = get_post_meta($post_id, $count_key, true);
    if ($n > 999999999) {
        $n_format = number_format($n / 1000000000, 1) . 'B';
    } else if ($n > 999999) {
        $n_format = number_format($n / 1000000, 1) . 'M';
    } else if ($n > 999) {
            $n_format = number_format($n / 1000, 1) . 'K';
    } else {
        $n_format = $n;
    }

    echo $n_format;
}
}
```

it works fine using this php code to show views `<?php mvp_post_views(); ?>`

Thou would like to show views using specified posts ID...

Comment: `if ($count=='')` should be `if (!$count)` as `get_post_meta` returns false not an empty string if the key is not set. otherwise seems okay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass post id as argument in the views function. Please check following example. An optional argument is passed in the function. If nothing is passed, id is fetched from `get_the_ID()`.

```
if ( !function_exists( 'mvp_post_views' ) ) {
    function mvp_post_views( $post_id = '' ){
        if ( $post_id ) {
            $post_id = absint( $post_id );
        } else {
            $post_id = get_the_ID();
        }
        $count_key = 'post_views_count';
        $n = get_post_meta($post_id, $count_key, true);
        if ($n > 999999999) {
            $n_format = number_format($n / 1000000000, 1) . 'B';
        } else if ($n > 999999) {
            $n_format = number_format($n / 1000000, 1) . 'M';
        } else if ($n > 999) {
            $n_format = number_format($n / 1000, 1) . 'K';
        } else {
            $n_format = $n;
        }
        echo $n_format;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks A lot Sir